# Ember hasMany and size of array(s)

Tags: ember.js, one-to-many

I have a relation hasMany and I want get the next index number. So, in my controller I have :

```
    nextStepIndex: Ember.computed(function () {
        return this.get('floor').get('steps').get('length') + 1;
    }).property('nextStepIndex')
```

I used too :

```
    nextStepIndex: Ember.computed(function () {
        return this.get('floor').get('steps.length') + 1;
    }).property('nextStepIndex')
```

But the length is always 0. The step is not saved and the floor too. All object was just created with createdRecord and the step is added with pushObject.

I saw in the steps relation they have a lot or array :

```
   DS.PromiseManyArray 
   DS.PromiseArray
   ArrayProxy
   MutableArray
   Array
```

My "step" object is in the ArrayProxy. So when I call the length method what size I will obtain?

So, if I can get the child record in the {{#each}} template directive, I expect to have the right size when I call the length method.

I known I can get the ArrayProxy size, but I don't want make a assumption on the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if your "property" is not set correctly

```
property('floor.steps.[]')
```

Also keep in mind it won't get triggered unless you call it from template or use it in another relation in component/controller.

Btw if your're dealing with async "steps" then computed property wont just do it out of box. You would need to use

```
nextStepIndex: function() {
        var stepsPromise = this.get('floor.steps');

        return DS.PromiseArray.create({
            promise: stepsPromise.then(function(steps) {
                // return your logics here
            })
        });

 }.property('floor.steps.[]')
```

Comment: @Nacrylic If it worked for you. you can accept it as answer lols.